Application Insights KQL query - not in sub query
How can I return results of a query that aren't in the results of another query? For example, I want to return the results that are returned from the first query and are not also in the second query:
First query:
customEvents
| extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
| extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
| extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
| where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
| where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "False"
| project TransactionNumber

e.g. if the above returned
145
167
100
94
56

Second query:
customEvents
| extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
| extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
| extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
| where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
| where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "True"
| project TransactionNumber

e.g. if the above returned
94
95
96
97
167
100

I want the result set to be:
145
56

I've tried the following but that doesn't appear to return the results from the failures query that aren't in the results of the successes query:
let failures = (customEvents
    | extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
    | extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "False"
    | project TransactionNumber);
let successes = (customEvents
    | extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
    | extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "True"
    | project TransactionNumber);
failures
| join kind=fullouter (successes) on TransactionNumber
| where isnull(TransactionNumber)
| project TransactionNumber


Did the error got resolved? Or are you still looking for an answer?

Still looking for an answer

Posted an answer @Bhav ..

Try doing an anti-join:
let failures = (customEvents
    | extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
    | extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "False"
    | project TransactionNumber);
let successes = (customEvents
    | extend Product = tostring(customDimensions.["Is Successful"])
    | extend TransactionNumber = tostring(customDimensions.["Transaction Number"])
    | extend StoreCode = tostring(customDimensions.["StoreCode"])
    | where name contains 'Transaction Posted' and customDimensions.['Transaction Number'] != ''
    | where customDimensions.["Is Successful"] == "True"
    | project TransactionNumber);
failures
| join kind=anti(successes) on TransactionNumber
| project TransactionNumber

Mark the whole code and execute it.

That doesn't return results that are in the first result set and not the second. For example, 0286200624913433 is a failed transaction number and is returned as part of failures result set and its not in the successes result set. The full query isn't returning any results but I'd expect 0286200624913433.

Ok, we can fix this. I just wanted to fix your error message from your initial question.

I´ve fixed my query in my answer. What about doing an anti-join. Is this the solution you are expecting?

You can integrate your query like below KQL Query:
let failures = datatable(TransactionNumber: int)
[
 145,167,100,94,56
];
let successes = datatable(TransactionNumber: int)
[
94,95,96,97,167,100
];
failures
| join kind=leftanti (successes) on TransactionNumber

Output:

Fiddle.

I didn´t know that there is a playground for KQL queries. Cool. good to know.
